# Parse json response in python

Tags: python, json

The workplace api returns a json response:

```
    {
    "name": "AA",
    "owner": {
        "name": "ser1",
        "id": "1234"
    },
    "id": "567",
    "admins": {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "codez",
                "id": "457"
            },
        ],
        "paging": {
            "cursors": {
                "before": "qwrqwreqreqr",
                "after": "teyryryryr"
            }
        }
    }
```

I access the json response in python using the below for loop:

```
for item in feed:
    row = [item["name"],item["id"], item["email"], item["privacy"],item["updated_time"],item["admins"]["data"]["name"]]
```

I get the error `"list indices must be integers or slices, not list"`. When I remove the `item["admins"]["data"]["name"]`, I don't get the error message.

Any suggestions would be appreciated !!

Comment: `item["admins"]["data"][0]["name"]` because `item["admins"]["data"]` is a list

Comment: because with `item["admins"]["data"]` you get an array, not a dict. If you wanna get a name from the array, you should use a inner loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access list. The data node contains a list so you need to access index 0 then access the key value pair.

```
for item in feed:
    row = [item["name"],item["id"], item["email"], item["privacy"],item["updated_time"],item["admins"]["data"][0]["name"]]
```

Comment: Even with item["admins"]["data"][0]["name"], I get the error "Keyerror:admins". Its not able to access nested dictionary

Comment: that must mean that response you are receiving from API is something else now. Use print and try to debug. The error you posted says that it was able to access admins key.

Answer (score 0):

data maps to a list with size one so you could do item["admins"]["data"][0]["name"]

Although this could be done much easier with row = item.values()

Comment: Even with item["admins"]["data"][0]["name"], I get the error "Keyerror:admins". Its not able to access nested dictionary

Comment: can you output the full workplace api response @user3447653

Comment: I have put the whole api response in my question

Comment: what is posted in the question is not valid json. I assumed it was a snippet. So either it isn't the full response or the response is not valid json